# Ghidra python - get string x-refs in a binary

Tags: ghidra, python

In Ghidra, there is `Defined Strings` window, that lists all the strings in the binary and their location.

I want to access the strings from Ghidra Python, and to get all the x-refs to those strings.

Any ideas on how is it possible to access this string info from Ghidra Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one method to do it.

```
from ghidra.program.util import DefinedDataIterator
from ghidra.app.util import XReferenceUtil

for string in DefinedDataIterator.definedStrings(currentProgram):
  for ref in XReferenceUtil.getXRefList(string):
    print(string, ref)
```

There are alternative [`definedStrings`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/util/DefinedDataIterator.html) iterators and other ways to use [`XReferenceUtil`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/app/util/XReferenceUtil.html) in the docs.